# K-9 Mail: Search in Message

Tags: search, k9-mail

I use K-9 Mail for Android. Recently I tried to search for text in a (rather long) email, but could not find any possibility to do so. Long-pressing the menu button results in a search field, which returns a list of messages containing the search phrase.

I would like to search for text inside of one particular message. Any suggestions on how to do that with K-9 Mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an Update of K-9 Mail I tried again to find it and succeeded (don't know whether this worked in a version prior to the new one).

This is how you search in K-9 Mail inside a message: In the respective message

1. select any text;
2. in the upcoming menu (copy, past, select all), select the document with a magnifying glass on it;
3. now the text you selected is used for an in-message search;
4. edit the search box and enter your search string.